# Can't connect to database 'embedded_db', available server_db

Tags: ruby, neo4j, jruby

I am trying to connect to the neo4j-database-files (embedded) from ruby.

Now I am getting this error:

Can't connect to database 'embedded_db', available server_db (Neo4j::Session::InitializationError)

Is using the embedded-connection only possible with JRuby? I am currently using the "standard" ruby.

Or is it because the folder is empty? How would I create an empty new database (embedded-ly) from within Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the docs, answering my own question:

Connecting to the neo4j-files is possible only from within the jRuby-Process:

http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.org/en/stable/Setup.html